# SenseNet Content Security Model How to read View PermissionInfoView

Tags: sensenet

Please explain how content security works on SenseNet.

Especially how to read the following SN database view:

- PermissionInfoView

What EFEntries(LocalOnly) flag is used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell: it works very similarly to the **file system permissions** in Windows.

You can define permissions for individual **users**, or (more preferably) **groups** and org units. Defining a permission happens on a content, usually on a container like a workspace or folder. For example you give *Open* and *Save* permissions *for the Editors group on the Articles folder*.

There is **inheritance**: child content will inherit permissions you defined on the parent folder (unless it was defined as **local only**, which means *not propagated to children*). For example if you define a *local only Save permission* on a document library for John, he will be able to modify the doclib content itself (e.g. change its display name), but not the files inside the library.

To make things a bit more complex, you can **break permissions** on a content, for example to *remove an inherited permission*. This may be necessary if you want to hide a subfolder.

For details please visit the [Permission System](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Permission_System) article.

#### Permission overview GUI

If you have installed the *WebPages* component of SN7, you get a [Permission Overview](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Permission_Overview) page that may help you understand the current permission settings in the tree.

#### The Permission info database view

In case you have the *Services* component only (so no GUI) or you really want to look under the hood, you can check out this db view to see all the permission settings in the system.

The records here contain all the *defined* permission entries in the system (so inherited ones cannot be seen here, they are calculated in memory). The Path is the content where the permissions are defined, the Identity can be a user or group, **LocalOnly** means not propagated to children (see above), the rest is a list of permissions (e.g. Open or Save) and whether they are *allowed*, *denied* or *undefined*.

For details about this and other db elements please visit the [DB structure](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Database_structure#Security) article.